# Erro Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Criei um site em c#, o mesmo roda na minha máquina, mas quando publico e atualizo no servidor via FTP(Filezilla) aparece essa mensagem, alguém pode me dar uma dica de como resolver ?

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado.

Comment: Você precisa incluir esta dll nos arquivos que vão para o servidor.

Comment: Em qual servidor você está tentando publicar a sua aplicação? Alguns servidores como locaweb ou até mesmo godaddy, dependendo do plano precisam de permissões especiais para o diretório de destino.

Answer (score 1):

Isto ocorre pois o servidor que você está utilizando não possui alguns arquivos que são necessários para a execução do seu aplicativo.

Você pode pegar as dependências do projeto e colocar junto na pasta bin. Você seleciona a(s) dlls que estão ocorrendo esse erro nas referências do seu projeto (`NomeDoProjeto/References` ou `NomeDoProjeto/Referencias`) e ir nas propriedades (`Alt+Enter`) e alterar o valor da propriedade Copiar `Local/Copy Local` para `true`.

Isso deve resolver os seus problemas!

Answer (score 0):

Instale AspNetMVC3ToolsUpdateSetup que pode ser descarregado  [daqui](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=1491) . Isto irá resolver o problema.

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14322426/194717